# C# Error: “; expected”, i've no idea where I'm missing it

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do here is to write a code which can find all the Prime numbers in a given range.

My code have two try-catch sections that raise the following error:

> "Error    CS1513  } expected"

And both of them are correctly surrounded by "{" before catch and "}" after.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PreimZahlen2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> Primezahlen_Liste = new List<int>();
            int UnterGrenze;
            int UberGrenze;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("UnterGrenze:");
                    UnterGrenze = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nur Integer Zahl bitte");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("UberGrenze:");
                    UberGrenze = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nur Integer Zahl bitte");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int Zahl = UnterGrenze; Zahl <= UberGrenze; Zahl++)
            {
                bool Zustand = true;
                if (Zahl == 2)
                {
                    Zustand = true;
                }
                else if (Zahl == 1 || Zahl % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Zustand = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 3; i <= (int)Math.Sqrt(Zahl) + 1; i += 2)
                    {
                        if (Zahl % i == 0)
                        {
                            Zustand = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Zustand == true)
                {
                    Primezahlen_Liste.Add(item: Zahl);
                }
            }
            string line = string.Join(",", values: Primezahlen_Liste.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            Console.WriteLine("Die Zahl der PreimZahlen in disem Bereich ist " + Primezahlen_Liste.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Druecken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else should work perfectly fine.

Comment: The first `else` has no `if` before it.

Comment: Why is there an `else` clause? Also maybe you would rather use `int.TryParse()` than try/catch exceptions thrown

Comment: The `else` statement is unneeded,where behind `catch`

Comment: There is no `try` ... `catch` ... `else` syntax in C#.

Comment: You have a try catch block followed by else?

Comment: ok thanks the code is working now  i just start learning C# and i've used Python for a while so i thought it may be the same try except else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code shorter by using `int.TryParse`:

```
    Console.Write("UnterGrenze:");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UnterGrenze))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nur Integer Zahl bitte");
        Console.Write("UnterGrenze:");
    }
    Console.Write("UberGrenze:");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UberGrenze))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nur Integer Zahl bitte");
        Console.Write("UberGrenze:");
    }
```

`int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UnterGrenze)` returns true if the value entered from the console is an integer type and false if it's not an integer type.If it's an integer type the entered value from the console is assigned to the `UnterGrenze` variable, and the while loop stops iterating.